# Third clickdown menu item won't come down

Tags: javascript

I started writing a responsive navigation bar (4 menu item) with two clickdowns. Now, I would like to add a third one. But when I add a third one, it won't dropdown. Earlier someone helped me with the second one (which also didn't drop down) and it works. So I thought I'd just copy the JS from the second one but that didn't work. Can someone tell me what I need to do in order for the third one to also dropdown? Thx!

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

/*If you bind 2 onclick then only last one will fire*/

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    removeShow("dropdown-content");
  }

  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
    removeShow("dropdown-content2");
  }
}

function removeShow(className) {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
/* Navigation */

.navbar-0 {
  height: auto;
}

.navbar-1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 0px;
}

.home,
.contact {
  padding: 5px;
}
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
/*2e drop*/
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content2 a {
  color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content2 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
/*3e drop*/
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown3 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content3 a {
  color: #FB4D4D;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content3 a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 navbar-0">
  <div class="col-10 col-container col-center-block navbar-1">
    <div class="colom col-3 home"><strong><a href="index.php">HOME</a></strong></div>
    <div class="colom col-3 dropdown aanbod">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">ONS AANBOD</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content col-12">
        <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2">WebDesign</a>
        <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6">Retoucheren</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colom col-3 dropdown2 portfolio">
      <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">PORTFOLIO</button>
      <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2 col-12">
        <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4">Websites</a>
        <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7">Retoucheringen</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colom col-3 dropdown spelers">
      <button onclick="myFunction3()" class="dropbtn3">SPELERS</button>
      <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content3 col-12">
        <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2">A-Kern</a>
        <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6">B-Kern</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colom col-3 contact"><strong><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8">CONTACT</a></strong></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are calling myFunction3, but it is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling myFunction3 but not defined you have to create myFunction3 in 
    js.

```
function myFunction3() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Appreciate if useful.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! The reason I didn't include the myFunction3 in this code is because I tried something similar like your code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick buttons should be ...

```
<button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown')"  class="dropbtn">ONS AANBOD</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown2')" class="dropbtn">PORTFOLIO</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown3')" class="dropbtn">SPELERS</button>
```

... and your function `myFunction` should look like this:

```
function myFunction(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
```